# Adding multiple controllers for same widget

Tags: flutter, dart

so I'm building an app on flutter and I guess I made a mistake after some heavy work(all inputs are the same widget).
I have multiple inputs (Form) and I create this widget which contains a `TextField` with my custom design.
Is it possible to add controller (ie: in mail input I need to check if entered string contains "@" . in name input it should be from A-Z a-z etc .. i guess you got my point).

This is my widget :

```
Widget makeInput({label, obscureText = false}) {
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      label,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.white),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    TextField(
      obscureText: obscureText,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800], width: 2.0),
          )),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 25,
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first I would start by defining the controllers like this

```
final _emailController = TextEditingController();
final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
```

then I would modify the widget to this (just changed parameters and inside the TextFormField).

```
Widget MakeInput(label, obscureText, validator, controller) {
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      label,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.white),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    TextFormField(
      obscureText: obscureText,
      controller: controller,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800], width: 2.0),
          )
      ),
      validator: validator
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 25,
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

I changed the obscureText parameter, because it will be easy for you passing to that function and not seting it value fixed to false(in case you have or want to add a password field to the form).
I also changed your textField widget to TextFormField so u can use the validator functions passed to the widget parameters to validate the fields.
In case u got stuck using them check [the documentation here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

So here is the function I think will help you validating the email field.

```
String? emailInputValidator(value) {
   if (value!.isEmpty || !RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                                .hasMatch(value)) return 'Enter a valid email';
}
```

I'm not a big fan of using Regex to validate username, so I prefer using this validation from the documentation (just a suggestion, u can look for regex if you really need it).

```
String? nameInputValidator(value){
if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
}
```

so inside your Form, u can call your widget like this:

```
MakeInput("Enter your e-mail", false, emailInputValidator, _emailController),
SizedBox(height:10),
MakeInput("Enter your name", false, nameInputValidator, _usernameController)
```

Comment: Thank you. Everything works as expected + some form validation and how to link form to my button. Thank you sir .